# Node.js event loop questions

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I am relatively new to javascript and node.js and I was looking into how the event loop worked as well as asynchronous programming
When I ran this code

```
function time(ms){
    return new Promise((resolve) =>{
        setTimeout(resolve,time)
    })
}

async function foo(){
    await time(2000)
    console.log("hi ")
    await time(2000)
    console.log("hello")
    await time(1000)
    console.log("bar")


}
foo()
console.log("a")
setTimeout(()=> console.log("b"),10)
```

The output was

> ```
> a
> hi 
> hello
> b
> bar
> ```

when I expected it to be

> ```
> a
> b
> hi  
> hello  
> bar
> ```

Then when I changed the last line to

```js
setTimeout(()=> console.log("b"),3000)
```

I thought the output would be

> ```
> a
> hi  
> b  
> hello   
> bar
> ```

but it was

> ```
> a
> hi
> hello  
> bar  
> b
> ```

Now I think there's something about the event loop that I'm not understanding because based on my understanding of the task queue and call stack my outputs should be correct but they aren't.

Comment: You should use `setTimeout(resolve, ms)`, **not** `setTimeout(resolve, time)`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your time function
Instead of

```js
setTimeout(resolve,time)
```

you should write

```js
setTimeout(resolve,ms)
```

Small explanation. In your current realization, you try to `setTimeout(...)` to `NaN` msec, 'cause variable `time` has type `Function` and cast to `NaN`